# reverse map value c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, reverse

I created a map:

```
map<int, int> mapOriginal;
```

after that fill with data, looks like this:

```
mapOriginal[0] = 3;
mapOriginal[1] = 2;
mapOriginal[2] = 1;
```

and the mapOriginal ouptut is:

```
  0->  3
  1->  2
  2->  1
```

I would like to create another map:

```
map<int, int> mapReverse;
```

But how can I reverse the mapOriginal value to the mapReverse:

and the mapReverse  ouptut  would be:

```
  0-> 1
  1-> 2
  2-> 3
```

Comment: Are your keys always in sequential order, starting at 0?

Comment: Why don't you just loop through it and assign each value at position `i` to mapReverse position `n-i`?

Comment: Thanks! and how can I iterate over the original?

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin That only works if the keys are sequential starting at 0.

Comment: This is an uncommon requirement, are you sure a map is the appropriate container to use in the first place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can iterate over your map forward and backwards at the same time:

```
std::map<int, int>::const_iterator forwardIt = mapOriginal.begin();
std::map<int, int>::const_reverse_iterator reverseIt = mapOriginal.rbegin();
for ( ;
    forwardIt != mapOriginal.end() ;
    ++forwardIt, ++reverseIt)
{
    mapReverse[forwardIt->first] = reverseIt->second;
}
```

However, that seems like an unusual use of maps. Are you sure a vector would not fulfill your needs?

```
std::vector<int> vec { 3, 2, 1 };

std::vector<int> reverseVec;
std::reverse_copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::back_inserter(reverseVec));
// or, if you want to reverse in-place:
std::reverse(vec.begin(), vec.end());
```

Answer (score 1):

the STL provides the concept of iterators for walking over the contents of container types. All STL containers should support iterators.
this approach using reverse iterators should be the most straight forward

```
map<int, int> mapOriginal;

mapOriginal[0] = 3;
mapOriginal[1] = 2;
mapOriginal[2] = 1;

map<int, int>reverseMap;

auto reverseIT = mapOriginal.rbegin();

for(auto forwardIT = mapOriginal.begin(); forwardIT != mapOriginal.end(); forwardIT++, reverseIT++)
{
    reverseMap[forwardIT->first] = reverseIT->second;        
}
```

note, rbegin() returns an iterator to the last element and incrementing a reverse iterator decrements it's position, moving it towards the begining of the container

Comment: How does this "reverse" the map? Both maps will be identical.

Comment: @Sancho i may have rushed my original response. I've updated my answer, which should work

Comment: Cool. It's basically the accepted answer now :) (with c++11 instead)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a ReverseMap or an ordered map?
If you want reverse a solution is

```
int size=3;
for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
mapReverse(i)=mapOriginal(size-i);
```

Else you can order by your array.

Comment: How do you know the keys will always be 0, 1, and 2?

Comment: That's why i put an size variable.

Comment: But what if the keys are 4, 8, and -3.

Comment: @Mhche, but the size variable is 3, and your for loop only goes over 0, and 1. And your first read from `mapOriginal` is from position `3`, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

If your map is one-to-one (each unique key has a unique value), just iterate through like so:

```
for (auto&& p : initial_map)
    reverse_map[p.second] = p.first;
```

In the general case, maybe construct a map from ints to lists of ints, and construct it as follows:

```
std::map<int, std::list<int>> reverse_map;
for (auto&& p : initial_map)
    reverse_map[p.second].push_back(p.first);
```

This assumes you have a C++11 compiler. You can replace the range-based for loops with regular for loops and iterators for C++98/03.

Comment: I had answered something like this, but this is not the kind of reversal OP is after.

Comment: Ah, I see. Not really reversing the map, but flipping it upside down.

Comment: Yeah, something like that. Flipping one side of it upside down.

Answer (score 0):

- Get a list of your keys in sorted order: `sorted_keys` (of size `n`)
- For each (`key`, `value`) pair in your original map:

  - Determine the `key`'s position `i` in the `sorted_keys`
  - Insert into the new map the key-value pair: (`sorted_keys[n - i - 1]`, `value`)